# Want To Create A Floating Speech Bubble Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Wondering if someone could help me....

I have a small .NET application where I have an Edit button on a main form.  When the user clicks the Edit button, I want to popup a small form right next to it (on top of the main form) with a speech balloon tail attached on the side of the form pointing to the Edit button.  So it gives the effect of a floating form pushed out from the Edit button.

I don't want the appearance of a normal speech bubble, I want it to look like an actual borderless form (with square corners).  It could be a custom control or anything (however, I am not yet familiar with creating my own custom controls), but I need to add Text Controls, Pictures, Label Controls, etc. to this floating form.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

**UPDATE**
I am trying to create something to this affect:
[image]

So imagine the ? being the Edit button and the other being a form with custom controls.

Comment: Yeah it could be a dialog or a form.  But ultimately I want to design a form and then call that up (either inside a dialog or a custom drawn form shape).  Which ever option is easier to create the desired effect.

Comment: there are several articles/tools/controls/toys on CodeProject putting all sorts of stuff in popup windows using the toolstrip drop down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

To get this behavior:

1. Select an image which will represent your speech bubble. Put a PictureBox on the form, make it use this image. Place two labels, as above, adjust the font.
2. Pick your transparency key (color). Your image background and form background need to be set to that. I used black for demo purposes, which is a bad choice if you plan to have any black or text in your speech bubble. Set form's `TransparencyKey` property to this color in designer. [More about TransparencyKey on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
3. (final step, not shown on the screenshot). Set `FormBorderStyle = None`.

Also make sure you have other ways to close your bubble, because X will be unavailable.

The final result may look something like the following:

[image]

**Note:** You may notice some drawing artifacts, most images on the internet have smooth borders, and transparency key does not support shades, has to be exact color. If you are fine with these minor artifacts, feel free to leave it at that. Or, edit it to get rough borders. Or find another one that better suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Neolisk, but I am trying to create something more like this: [link](http://www.designvsart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/shoppingcom.png)

Comment: @user2185200: Same principle applies. Use any shape/image you want. Hold on a sec, do you want your tooltip fully opaque? (non-transparent)

Comment: Yes I would like it fully opaque

Comment: @user2185200: Not a problem, I am going to update my answer. Still, same general principle applies.

Comment: Okay, I have simulated your example and it works exactly how I wanted so thankyou....one last question before I mark this as accepted...I have used Red as my transparency colour, but I am getting a 1 pixel red border around the outside of my form now.  Any way I can fix this?  Your example shows a crisp border.

Comment: Never mind, I tidied up the edging in photoshop and used a different colour.  Looks much nicer now.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @user2185200: I used paint to fix "almost white pixels" on your image, then fill the outside with my transparency color.